# Android :: Layer-List 3 vertical rectangle stack issue

Tags: android, xml-layout, layer-list

**PROBLEM**

I want to create 3 rectangles in the vertical. Then, I want the first and the last one transparent. but the result look like the second rectangle height is bigger than it should be (its height big equal 2 rectangle)

**PICTURE**

Before it transparent... 
[image]

After it transparent...
[image]

What I want...
[image]

**XML LAYER-LIST**

```
<layer-list xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:top="0dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <size android:height="5dp" android:width="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>
            <size android:height="5dp" android:width="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="10dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
            <size android:height="5dp" android:width="20dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**UPDATE ANSWER**

change above to these solve the problem as **`Rod_Algonquin`** answer in this question

```
<item android:top="0dp" android:bottom="10dp">
<item android:top="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
<item android:top="10dp" android:bottom="0dp">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**problem:**

```
<item android:top="5dp">
```

since you are only giving it a `top of 5dp` it will only crop the top with 5dp and still have the height covering almost the size of the layer

**solution:**

add a `bottom attribute` to crop the bottom as well to balance the effect you want

```
<item android:top="5dp"  android:bottom="5dp">
```

Comment: So as you said I have change value and it work thank !